# How to count elements in tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor for example : `X = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]`.

And what I want is to reduce this tensor `X` to a tensor such as: `Y = [3, 4, 3]`.

Where `Y` in position 0 is the count of how many 0s there are in `X`, and the position 1 how many 1s, so on and so forth.

What I'm doing right now is iterating through this tensor using the `tf.where` function. But this doesn`t seem elegant, and there must be a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for `Y = tf.bincount(X)`:

```
X = tf.constant([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
Y = tf.bincount(X)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
Y.eval()

# output
#[3, 4, 3]
```

For negative integers you can use:

```
tf.bincount(X + tf.abs(tf.reduce_min(X)) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts).

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.constant([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
op = tf.unique_with_counts(X)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res = sess.run(op)
print(res.count)
# [4 3 3]
```

Beware that `tf.bincount` only handle *positive integers*. If your input tensor is not of integer type, or contains negative values, you must use `tf.unique_with_count`. Otherwise `bincount` is fine and to the point.